Why does ManyToOne relationship only get resolved in subsequent Request in Spring JPA?
I have a very basic web app. Basically, you call the rest interface and a new company with 2 employees is created. You can also fetch a companies data:
@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepository;
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PostMapping("/company")
    public Company createCompany() {

        // Generate a new name
        String name = "Company" + companyRepository.count();

        Company company = new Company(name);
        company=companyRepository.save(company);

        Employee John= new Employee("John", company);
        employeeRepository.save(John);
        Employee Jane= new Employee("Jane", company);
        employeeRepository.save(Jane);

        company=companyRepository.findById(company.getCompanyName()).orElseThrow();

        return company;
    }

    @GetMapping("/company/{id}")
    public Company getCompany(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
        return companyRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    }
}

Here's how the Entites are defined:
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private final String name;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn()
    @JsonBackReference()
    private Company company;

    public Employee() {
        this.name = "";
    }

    public Employee(String name, Company company) {
        this.name = name;
        this.company = company;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

}


@Entity
public class Company {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")
    private final String companyName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="company",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public Company(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public Company() {
        this.companyName = "";
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
}

But one the post request I get this result (no employees have been added, even though they have):
{
    "companyName": "Company0",
    "employees": null
}

Yet on the subsequent request, it works:
{
    "companyName": "Company0",
    "employees": [
        {
            "name": "John"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jane"
        }
    ]
}

I find this behaviour extremely strange, I am reloaded the company once again in the post request after all.
So can someone tell me why this happens?

You have to add the Employees to the employee list of the Company, too.
Since you added Cascade all, it's probably the only thing you have to do, before saving the company. I think the company isn't marked dirty after saving the employees, so you get the cached company from the save without employees...

It's not so much that I really want to get the company with all the employees, I'd like to understand what happens in the background of spring JPA that causes this behavior

You aren't managing both sides of the relation, the findById returns the cached version which has no relations yet in your method. Subsequent calls will actually get a fresh instance and thus with relations. When doing things with bi-directional relationships you also need to properly manage both sides of it, else you can get strange issues.

What do you mean by cached version? Doesn't findById correspond to an SQL Query to the server?
